# Print map function's output list using mapM_ / putStrLn

Tags: haskell, monads

I tried to print map function's list output using putStrLn as,

```
main = do
  let out = "hello\nworld\nbye\nworld\n"
  putStrLn $ map ("out: " ++) $ lines out
```

It throws error as,

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
```

I referred some other code and changed the lastline to

```
  mapM_ putStrLn $ map ("out: " ++) $ lines out
```

It solves the problem, but how does map monad with underscore suffix work in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapM_` is based on the `mapM` function, which has the type

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

And `mapM_` has the type

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

With the former, it acts like the normal `map` over a list, but where each element has an action run with the results aggregated.  So for example if you wanted to read multiple files you could use `contents <- mapM readFile [filename1, filename2, filename3]`, and `contents` would be a list where each element represented the contents of the corresponding file.  The `mapM_` function does the same thing, but throws away the results.  One definition is

```
mapM_ f list = do
    mapM f list
    return ()
```

Every action gets executed, but nothing is returned.  This is useful in situations like yours where the result value is useless, namely that `()` is the only value of type `()` and therefore no actual decisions can be made from it.  If you had `mapM putStrLn someListOfStrings` then the result of this would have type `IO [()]`, but with `mapM_ putStrLn someListOfStrings` the `[()]` is thrown away and just replaced with `()`.